# Custom PyQt signal never received by QSignalTransition subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qstatemachine

Trying to learn PyQt5 `QStateMachine` with transitions derived from `QSignalTransition` following [this example](https://github.com/pyside/Examples/blob/master/examples/state-machine/factstates.py) written for PySide. To use PyQt I just changed the definition of the signal, and the way it is referenced in `QSignalTransition` initializer. This is the complete code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QSignalTransition, QCoreApplication, QStateMachine, QState, QFinalState


class Factorial(QObject):
    xChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Factorial, self).__init__()
        self.xval = -1
        self.facval = 1
    def getX(self):
        return self.xval
    def setX(self, x):
        if self.xval == x:
            return
        self.xval = x
        self.xChanged.emit(x)
    x = property(int, getX, setX)
    def getFact(self):
        return self.facval
    def setFact(self, fac):
        self.facval = fac
    fac = property(int, getFact, setFact)

class FactorialLoopTransition(QSignalTransition):
    def __init__(self, fact):
        super(FactorialLoopTransition, self).__init__(fact.xChanged[int])
        self.fact = fact
    def eventTest(self, e):
        if not super(FactorialLoopTransition, self).eventTest(e):
            return False
        return e.arguments()[0] > 1
    def onTransition(self, e):
        x = e.arguments()[0]
        fac = self.fact.fac
        self.fact.fac = x * fac
        self.fact.x = x - 1

class FactorialDoneTransition(QSignalTransition):
    def __init__(self, fact):
        super(FactorialDoneTransition, self).__init__(fact.xChanged[int])
        self.fact = fact
    def eventTest(self, e):
        if not super(FactorialDoneTransition, self).eventTest(e):
            return False
        return e.arguments()[0] <= 1
    def onTransition(self, e):
        print(self.fact.fac)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    factorial = Factorial()
    machine = QStateMachine()

    compute = QState(machine)
    compute.assignProperty(factorial, 'fac', 1)
    compute.assignProperty(factorial, 'x', 6)
    compute.addTransition(FactorialLoopTransition(factorial))

    done = QFinalState(machine)
    doneTransition = FactorialDoneTransition(factorial)
    doneTransition.setTargetState(done)
    compute.addTransition(doneTransition)

    machine.setInitialState(compute)
    machine.finished.connect(app.quit)
    machine.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This state machine just compute the factorial of 6 and print it.

My problem is, in both transitions, this piece of code:

```
def eventTest(self, e):
    if not super(FactorialDoneTransition, self).eventTest(e):
        return False
    return e.arguments()[0] <= 1
```

returns `False` on the first and only call. I assume this is because the event passed is not of the proper type, and the superclass returns `False`. With this behavior the transitions are never executed, and the the state machine remains at its initial state.

Can someone explain what is the problem? Is it my conversion from PySide to PyQt which is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`assignProperty()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstate.html#assignProperty) method expects a Q_PROPERTY that in the case of PySide/PySide2 equals Property (which is different from the property provided by python natively) and in the case of PyQt4/PyQt5 you must use [pyqtProperty](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/qt_properties.html#PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtProperty), and that is the cause of the error so the solution is to replace with the following:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QSignalTransition, QCoreApplication, QStateMachine, QState, QFinalState, pyqtProperty


class Factorial(QObject):
    xChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Factorial, self).__init__()
        self.xval = -1
        self.facval = 1

    def getX(self):
        return self.xval

    def setX(self, x):
        if self.xval == x:
            return
        self.xval = x
        self.xChanged.emit(x)

    x = pyqtProperty(int, getX, setX) # <---

    def getFact(self):
        return self.facval

    def setFact(self, fac):
        self.facval = fac

    fac = pyqtProperty(int, getFact, setFact) # <---

# ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation, that's exactly the solution. I don't understand why this led to sending an event of the improper type.

Comment: @mins The problem is that by not passing a proper value the state machine starts but never finished so the QStateMachine finished signal was never emitted and consequently neither app.quit() that closes the application was invoked.

Comment: Actually, I see the first event sent is not a `SignalEvent`, even when the code is correct. So ok, before the correction no other events where sent, because the value of x was never changed.